# Cómo subo una app hecha con Next.js a Hostinger?

Tags: reactjs, hosting, next.js, next

Ya he subido varias webs a Hostinger con React haciendo el npm build... me creaba la carpeta "dist" y ya de ahí pan comido... Pero con Next al hacer npm build no me crea ninguna carpeta Dist... ¿Que estoy haciendo mal? Que más tengo que tener en cuenta?

Answer (score 1):

Por como estan construidas las aplicaciones de Next.js estas necesitan utilizar otros servicios que el host compartido de hostinger no incluye, sin embargo el servicio de VPS lo incluye, pero este esta pensado para almacenar aplicaciones con una escalabilidad muy alta que para un mortal creo que seria mejor utilizar el plan de host-compartido.